# Can I sort cells in Google Sheets with a key function?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sorting

I have some data in a Google Sheets document that I would like to sort by computing some value from two columns and using that as the sort key.

Say my data is like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | 8700 | 5 |
| 2 | ... | ... | 1 | 32000 |
| 3 | ... | ... | 0 | 4200 |
| 4 | ... | ... | 2500 | 7000 |

I want to sort the data in decending order based on `max(C, D)` so that the data looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | 1 | 32000 |
| 2 | ... | ... | 8700 | 5 |
| 3 | ... | ... | 2500 | 7000 |
| 4 | ... | ... | 0 | 4200 |

I was able to do it with a Python script like this, but that required exporting the sheet and then re-importing it.

```
import csv

with open('source_sheet.csv', newline='') as in_file, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_file)
    sorted_data = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: max(int(x['C']), int(x['D']), reverse=True)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(sorted_data)
```

Is there some formula or function that can do what I want?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result using built-in functions like this:

```
=sort(A1:D4,byrow(C1:D4,lambda(row,max(row))),0)
```